# Best way to join parent and child tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, view

I have Parent table `A`.
`A` has few child tables such as `B`,`C`,`D`,`E`,`F`,`G`
The child tables are not linked to each other. They are only linked to `A`.
`A` has a key `Id` which is used as foreign key in all the child tables.

What should be the best way to join these tables so I can create a single view on this?

Comment: That depends of what output do you want. Do you want different columns from different tables for same A value, or do you want common columns and separate rows?

Comment: @Nenad..bascally i need a logical view which should have all the records for all the tables, so that i can get any data from any of the tables using a single view..

Comment: It's unusual to want to do this, because if each of eight child tables has four records for a given parent then querying all of them at once will return 65,536 rows to the client. In general it is meaningless to join each child record to every record in every other child table.

Answer (score 6):

Since a parent may have a child row in some of those tables you must use LEFT OUTER JOIN.

LEFT OUTER JOIN joins two tables returning all the rows of the LEFT table, in this case A and all the matches from the other tables. When there is no match it will return NULL in the corresponding columns of the tables that there was no match.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
    ON A.Id = B.ParentID
LEFT OUTER JOIN C
    ON A.Id = C.ParentID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN P
        ON C.Id = P.ParentID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Q
        ON C.Id = Q.ParentID
LEFT OUTER JOIN D
    ON A.Id = D.ParentID
LEFT OUTER JOIN E
    ON A.Id = E.ParentID
LEFT OUTER JOIN F
    ON A.Id = F.ParentID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN X
        ON F.Id = X.ParentID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Y
        ON F.Id = Y.ParentID
LEFT OUTER JOIN G
    ON A.Id = G.ParentID
```

**EDIT**

I have added a way to add subchilds. I have intented them more just to make them obvious in a visual representation. But beware...if this lead to subchildren have other subchildren  etc maybe your structure is not optimal.

Comment: Suppose some of the childs have subchilds..for example `C` has childs `P` and `Q`..`F` has child `X` and `Y`..then should it work if i use JOIN for those subchilds also in the same query?

Comment: You should Left Join them accordingly. But it could lead to an infinite chain. What if for instance there where subchilds with their own subchilds....

Comment: Thanks..got it..yes in some cases i do have multi level of childs ..so i believe this should be the only approach i can follow as i need to go for a single view..is there anything we can go for better approach in terms of optimisation?

Comment: Well, it highly depends on what you want. Normalization dictates that each entity should have its own table, so if these are different entities-structures, you should have different tables. Even if you had one kind of entity like persons linking to other persons, again you would have to follow the above structure. My only  comment was to make you avoid having long chains of relations because you won't be able to really create a stored query. You will have to make it dynamic, and this would mean other complications....

Answer (score 2):

```
select <wanted columns>
from a
left join b
on a.id = b.a_id
left join c
on a.id = c.a_id
left join d
on a.id = d.a_id
```