# How to select record from select new clause in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code
I am having 3 tables as Department, DepartmentTask and DepartmentPosition. Here are the tables :

```
public partial class Department()
{
   public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
   public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
   public Nullable<int> ParentDepartmentId { get; set; }    
}
public partial class DepartmentPosition
{
    public int PositionId { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string PositiontName { get; set; }        
}
public partial class DepartmentTask
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string TaskName { get; set; }       
}
```

So any department can be a parent to another department, Task and Position. So here I want to select all the records from the tables which are children of a particular Department based on DepartmentId.

```
var z = from n in dbbs.Department
        select new
        {
            deptcount = dbbs.Department.Count(p => p.ParentDepartmentId == id),
            poscount = dbbs.DepartmentPosition.Count(x => x.DepartmentId == id),
            taskcount = dbbs.DepartmentTask.Count(t => t.DepartmentId == id)
        };
if(z.Count()>0)
{ 
//do something
}
else
{

}
```

and now if there are no record within tables still it is coming within if block. I want to know how to restrict if there are no records as per the query.

Comment: Let me guess and say the object it returns has counts of 0 inside z?

Comment: That's a very odd query - you're not using `n` at all. What are you actually trying to achieve? Why do you have two properties (`poscount` and `taskcount`) which are counting exactly the same thing?

Comment: @JonSkeet I am having 3 tables. Department tables record can be a parent to the rest of the tables and to itself also. Now here my idea is to check whichever table is having a child record  with parent as a record from department.

Comment: So why not just do three separate Count queries? (And it's still not clear why two of your queries are the same...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the select statement. Can you not use:

```
var deptcount = dbbs.Department.Count(p => p.ParentDepartmentId == id);
var poscount = dbbs.DepartmentPosition.Count(x => x.DepartmentId == id);
var taskcount = dbbs.DepartmentPosition.Count(t => t.DepartmentId == id);

if(deptcount > 0) 
{
 //do something
}
```

if you are trying to do a grouping based on the departments please explain and I'll update my answer.

Comment: if I do have 7 tables then do I need to write 7 queries is there any alternate sol. Thanks

Comment: as Jon says above it depends on what you want you want to achieve. You really need to explain this in enough detail for us to be able to help you. Can you explain if you were doing it in a database what you are hoping to get back and what tables you have?

Answer (score 0):

```
var count= from s in ObjectContext.tb1
                              join c in ObjectContext.tb2 on s.ParentCategoryID equals c.PersonCategoryID
                              join p in ObjectContext.tb3 on c.BusinessEntityID equals p.BusinessEntityID
                              select new count()
                              {
                                 tbl1count =c.count()
                                 tbl2count =p.count()
                                 tbl3count =p.count()
                              };
```

then

```
if(count.tbl1count.any()){
//do whatever you need}
```

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126255/best-way-to-join-parent-and-child-tables

Comment: var query =from p in  parentable join c in childatble 1 on c.foreign id equuals p.id join  join c2 in childatble2 on c.foreign id equuals p.id