# Best way to get all datasets from child tables of one parent record

Tags: mysql, select, parent-child

This is more a design question. I have a database layout like this (simplified):
[image]

So one user can have multiple counts of drinks, games and foods.

What is the best way to get all child datasets of one user?

Doing single selects for each child table and preparing data in script (PHP)?
I already tried to use Left Joins on userID but that resulted in a cartesian product with thousands of result rows.

Basically this thread describes my problem very good: [Best way to join parent and child tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126255/best-way-to-join-parent-and-child-tables)

And the comment there of David Aldridge also describes the issue with Left Joins:

> It's unusual to want to do this, because if each of eight child tables has four records for a given parent then querying all of them at once will return 65,536 rows to the client.

So if Left Joins are not suitable here, which way is the way to go?

Comment: What are your criteria for measuring 'bestness'?

Comment: i just want to know what the usual approach would be to gather all datasets. so the task is known, but which solution would you all take?